# Inverted-colors text on top of an OpenGL scene

Tags: opengl, text, colors, fonts

I have a font texture which I use in order to draw text on top of my OpenGL scene.
The problem is that the scene's colors vary so much that any solid color I use is hard to read. Is it possible to draw my font texture with inverted colors?

A call to `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);` would just draw it with a solid color, A call to `glBlendFunc(GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_COLOR, GL_ZERO);` would draw it inverted, but would disregard the alpha values of the texture so you'd just see an inverted rectangle instead of the letters.

What I need is something equivalent to 
`glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA * GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_COLOR, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`

Can this be achieved somehow *without using shaders* ?

Comment: Why can't you just use a luminance texture and glBlendFunc(GL_ONE_MINUS_DEST_COLOR, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_COLOR)?

Answer (score 4):

Following dave's comment:

Instead of using a GL_ALPHA texture I generate a GL_RGBA texture where each pixel is equal:
(alpha, alpha, alpha, 0xff) (this is a greyscale image instead of a luminance image).
Then I use this texture with:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_COLOR, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_COLOR);
```

The result is: `(1 - dest_color) x "src_alpha" + dest_color x (1 - "src_alpha")`
which is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the subsection of the screen you want to overwrite, you can use the CPU to invert this copied portion. Draw your newly made inverted texture to the screen using the text as a mask.

Note that this is slow, there's no doubt that shaders would be much faster.